# Customize register portlet in websphere portal 8

Tags: websphere-portal

when I try to register an account, the register form validates that the field "User ID" can't store special character like "@" ,but i need to register an account using email as "User ID". Thanks for your help

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean *don't let me do that*? Are you getting some error or warning?

Comment: Hi, when I try to register an account the form validate that the field

Comment: Sorry for last comment, it's incomplete!!  when I try to register an account, the register form validates that the field "User ID" can't store special character like "@" ,but i need to register an account using email as "User ID".

Comment: No worries no need to apologize :) You should edit your post and add your last comment since that kind of info is useful to help you. Always try to add as much info as possible to help people help you.